# How can I get the path of the call to MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to access (in a build file) the directory from which MSBuild.exe was called?

I have only been able to get the path of the build file itself. I want the directory from which MSBuild was called instead.

**Expected**

```
D:\> msbuild foo\foo.proj
...
  MSBuild was called from: D:\>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="MSBuild was called from: ???" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**Why**

I was wondering if one could replace the absolute path in

```
D:\workdir> msbuild foo\foo.proj /p:Parameter=d:\workdir\Projects\bar\
```

with a relative path

```
D:\workdir> msbuild foo\foo.proj /p:Parameter=Projects\bar\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [MSBuild Reserved and Well-Known Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx)

It looks like `MSBuildStartupDirectory` will help you:

**TestBuild.vcxproj snippet**

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="MSBuild was called from: $(MSBuildStartupDirectory)" />
  </Target>
```

**Build**

```
d:\Data\Visual Studio 2013\Projects>msbuild /m .\TestMsBuild\TestMsBuild\TestMsBuild.vcxproj /verbosity:detailed /t:BeforeBuild

Task "Message"
    MSBuild was called from: d:\Data\Visual Studio 2013\Projects
```